# iOS 13 Request Mobile Site

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I’ve noticed on iOS 13, safari automatically sets the webpage to desktop site, and I don’t see anyplace to set it back to the mobile site. Does anyone have a solution to request mobile site?

Comment: All sites, or just specific ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open up the menu to the left in the address bar - I think you'll find what you are looking for.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you, didn’t know it moved places.